# How to display error message in tooltip for confirm password?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-tooltip

Is there any way to display conform-password miss match error in tooltip.
And One more thing I need to display error window when the password miss match, and it should be like the same pop window showing the error when required field throws.

Comment: I recommend using "Tipsy" jquery tooltip, (http://www.1stwebmagazine.com/tipsy-jquery-tooltip) check it out it's really easy and useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" maxlength="100"   data-msg-required='Bevestig je wachtwoord' data-rule-required=true data-rule-equalto="#password1" data-rule-minlength="6" data-msg-minlength='Voer minimaal 6 karakters in'>
```